# Git repositories holding plugin repositories

Tags: git, plugins, version-control

I've been struggling with which approach to take with this project for while and decided to take some advice from the community.

We are developing an open source framework that allows others to use its features by implementing some interface. By implementing this interface others are essentially developing a plugin the this framework (or at least that's how I see it and will call it for the rest of this question).

We use git as the framework's version control. (eventually will be uploaded to Github or such).
And the project is built using CMake.

In addition to allowing others the option of developing plugins of their own, we have some implementations of our own that we want to provide as open source. This is both for providing a common usage, and also for tutorial purposes (showing how to implement the interface and other usages examlpes). In order to simulate real world development of such plugins, our plugin (let's call it Plugin1) is implemented in a different git repository than the framework.

In order to support compilation of both the framework and our plugins, the framework has a "plugins" folder which we expect to contain folders of CMake projects that provide an implementation of the interface. We don't assume anything on the projects, other than that they use CMake. (to add the plugins to the tree - add_subdirectory() is called via script that search through the plugins folder)

So basically we have something like this:

```
. (framework repository)
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── plugins
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── plugin1
│   ├── plugin2
│   ├── user_implemented_plugin_1
│   └── other plugins...
├── src
├── tests
└── etc...
```

Where each plugin under `./plugins/` is a different git repository (some our own and some might be user implementations).
So in order to download each plugin we `git clone` each repo (and if we need we checkout some specific tag).

We don't expect users to use this way (they should `make install` the framework or install it via package), but for our development it is convenient.

This way helps us test the framework in our build system (using simple script that downloads the plugins repos).
As I've said eventually this will become open source and we would like developers to download the framework as well as the plugins we developed. 
Here is where it might become inconvenient, since users will have to use a script to download the repositories, or will have to do it manually and I'm not sure this the best approach.

My question is really more of a request for advice and feedback.
I looked around the web for best practices and such for this sort of development but couldn't find anything. 
Some suggested to use google repo but it seemed like an overkill.
Some suggested using git submodule, but from my understanding this is for cases where the parent repo depends on the child repo and my case is the other way around.

Am I doing some rookie mistake developing the project like this? does git have some support for managing this sort of tree? are there any tools that you recommend to use?

Comment: For `git submodule`, this will make functions in plugins are also available for the framework. Is it meet your requirement?

Comment: No, I don't need the framework to depend on plugins. I need plugins to depend on framework

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose to make plugins to depend on framework, you can add the code from framework repo to thee plugin repos. Assume you want the code of `master` branch in framework repo apply in plugin repos, you can use

```
git subtree add --prefix=user <URL for framework repo> master
```

Comment: You add still use the way `git clone` to add repos in `./plugins` folder, just use `git subtree add` to each repo in `./plugins`.

Comment: Ok but what would that give me? What does it do?

Comment: After using `git subtree add` the functions of framework can also be used in your plugin.

Comment: Have you solve the problem and did the answer help you?

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on `git subtree`, can you provide a link?

Comment: Yes, of cause. You can refer https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt for more details about git subtree.

Comment: haven't gotten to it yet

Comment: What's the result if you use `git subree add` in plugin repos?